# Unable to send the cookie. Maximum number of cookies would be exceeded Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, cookie

Every time I open var/Repots in magento 2 website, I found hundreds and thousands of error files all having the same message:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:71:"Unable to send the cookie. Maximum number of cookies would be exceeded.";
i:1;s:12555:"#0 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(116): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->checkAbilityToSendCookie('form_key', '........')...
```

I searched a lot, but I did not find a solution. The maximum number of cookies is set to 50 by default.

The problem is not happening on my browser. It mostly happens with customers using android mobile phone's browser Android Version 4.0.2 to 4.4.0.

[Clearing cache or using private browsing](https://cait.calarts.edu/hc/en-us/articles/217055138-Error-Maximum-Number-of-Cookie-Values-Reached) solves the issue on the client side. However I need a server side solution. (I asked a customer to clear the cache and the problem is solved on his mobile).

Comment: How many cookies are set? Are all of them necessary?

Comment: actually I don't know. It is created automatically by the magento framework.

Comment: It is not happening in my browser. It mostly happens with customers using android 4.0.2 to 4.4.0 mobile browsers.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: It is 2.1.5 as mentioned in title

Comment: @MoeHammadi, Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I contacted Magento support since I have a golden support on my magento EE account. They sent me a patch which increases the number of cookies from 20 to 50. However It does not work since the maximum number of cookies allowed is already 50. 

So no solution yet.

Answer (score 6):

Extend in di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager" type="Project\Cookies\PhpCookieManager" />
```

```
<?php
namespace Project\Cookies;

class PhpCookieManager extends \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
{
    const MAX_NUM_COOKIES = 100;    // original 50
    const MAX_COOKIE_SIZE = 16384;  // original 4096
}
```

Comment: 666 max number of cookies? That can't be good

Comment: This is working fine. but better to copy file from vendor to lib directory.

Answer (score 4):

I Was able to solved this problem by increase   const MAX_COOKIE_SIZE = 40960;

public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php

```
const MAX_NUM_COOKIES = 50;
const MAX_COOKIE_SIZE = 40960;
const EXPIRE_NOW_TIME = 1;
const EXPIRE_AT_END_OF_SESSION_TIME = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This article should help give you a better idea on the Root Cause (i.e. how/what/why) of the issue - https://mage2.pro/t/topic/84/2

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Magento is in any hurry to fix the issue for Android OS based browsers  - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7931

Comment: I passed by those articles before. b

Comment: Upgrade to the latest Magento 2 version so.

Comment: is it solved in the latest version?

Comment: Per the Defect logs ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7931) the problem has been resolved in 2.2.x 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEoh7.png

Comment: I'm running 2.2.3 and I still get the issue regularly, the problem is not resolved. Trying to find a solution myself.

Comment: i'm running 2.3.4 , the problem is not resolved

Comment: @Jason-Diel Did you guys find solution to this problem?