# Magento 2 - After adding to cart, cart page showing empty

Tags: magento2, php, addtocart, varnish, linux

I have a magento 2 website and I am facing an issue where After you add to cart, cart page is showing empty.

It's not happening all the time but most of the customers are facing this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hello did you ever find a cause for this? I'm hoping for some help at least to troubleshoot a similar problem but so far I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Which version of magento 2 you are using, Can you please try to disable Full Page Cache then check it?

Comment: I'm on 2.2.4. The problem is rare and unpredictable, maybe 1 out of 50 users... certainly less are reporting it and there is nothing correlating in my logs to be certain either way. Disabling full page cache could be a disaster on my live site and like I said I can't recreate the issue on my own to test.

Comment: @jamil please check below answer, this will work.

Comment: Thanks, but my settings were already the same, except Cookie Lifetime. I have changed Cookie Lifetime to match my php setting `session.gc_maxlifetime`, although I'm not sure if this matters.

Comment: is your whole website is on HTTPS?

Comment: Yes and i'm seeing a lot of [errors like this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193034/unable-to-send-the-cookie-maximum-number-of-cookies-would-be-exceeded-magento-2) in `system.log`, although it supposed to be an android issue... not entirely sure its related though.

Comment: Set the correct cookie path in to core_config_data table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable this:

**Magento Admin > Stores > Settings / Configuration > General / Web > Default Cookie Settings**

[image]

Comment: this did not solve in my case. I had to clear the session in var folder. `rm -rf var/session/*`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by a Magento module not being enabled.

If you enable Magento_Persistent this issue will be fixed.

Comment: The Magento_Persistent module was already enabled. There seems issue with the session id generation. On my case, the issue was gone by clearing the session `rm -rf var/session/*`